# have to run a macro twice

Tags: excel, vba, adp

i need to run the macro twice for it to work

have no clue how to fix it

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tmp As Worksheet
Dim acct As String

Set ws = Sheets("Booking")
Set tmp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
tmp.Activate

On Error Resume Next
AppActivate "BTS", True
On Error GoTo 0
Sleep 1000

On Error Resume Next

SendKeys "MRGN", True 'enter margin
Sleep 500
SendKeys "^", True 'reset
Sleep 500
SendKeys "40911025", True ' enter account number
SendKeys "{F3}", True 'get balance secreen
Sleep 750 'waits X seconds
SendKeys "^{INSERT}", True 'copy
Sleep 100
tmp.Activate

tmp.Range("A1").Select
tmp.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

        ws.Range("I7") = Trim(Left(tmp.Range("A7"), 13)) 'GetEquity
        ws.Range("I9") = Trim(Left(tmp.Range("A9"), 13)) 'GetMM
        ws.Range("I11") = Trim(Left(tmp.Range("A11"), 13)) 'GetDebt
        ws.Range("I13") = Trim(Left(tmp.Range("A13"), 13)) 'GetL250

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

tmp.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Sheets("Booking").Activate
```

it works, but I need to run it twice.

Comment: Well, what's not working? Start by getting rid of the `On Error Resume Next`, so you can actually see any errors it raises.

Comment: While you're at it, use the [edit] link to format the code into a more readable format. Get rid of empty lines and make sure everything is indented by *at least* four spaces so that it's in a code block.

Comment: it breaks when pasting (tmp.pastespecial...")....for whtever reason, if i run it twice, it works...so messed up...the on error resume next was to bypass that error....it doesn't make sense that when i run it again, it works, right?

Comment: If `On Error Resume Next` is used to hide syntax errors, then the problem doesn't go away.  If you refer to the `Range.PasteSpecial` method, you are not following the format as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial

Answer (score 0):

If you need the macro to loop twice, set up a separate subroutine in the same module and just call the main subroutine twice. Kind of a brute force way to do it though, so I'd recommend not doing this often.

```
call main_subroutine_name() 
call main_subroutine_name()
```

Your issue however appears to be with the data that you're pasting. Are you trying to paste values, and where are you trying to paste the data? If you're trying to paste the data in range "A1," try:

```
range("A1").pastespecial ...
```

Since you already activated the specific sheet, you shouldn't need to specify the sheet as the region in which you're trying to paste, and can rather just reference cell "A1" as shown above.

Comment: i tried that, but it doesn't work (just use range("a1").paste...)  ...i get "complie error: named argument not found"

I tried doing range("a1").select
selection.pastespecial format....

but if i do that, it doesn't paste at all even if i run it twice....i think the code is such that because the information is being copy and pasted from ADP/Broadridge which literally looks like a DOS screen (or if youve ever seen Costco's system, it looks like that)

Comment: @dwightchang Have you tried doing this without VBA first to see what kind of paste methods work and then you can alter the pastespecial from there?

You could try specifically stating - 

Activeworkbook.sheets(tmp.name).range("A1").pastespecial ...


and see if that works?

Comment: sorry for not trying earlier guys, but....

     
     Range("a1").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     

seemed to do the trick